# Possible to already have a "ready cursor" in a serverless environment?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, serverless, google-cloud-run

Take the following two timings on a trivial SQL statement:

```
timeit.timeit("""
    import MySQLdb; 
    import settings; 
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host=settings.DATABASES['default']['HOST'], port=3306, user=settings.DATABASES['default']['USER'], passwd=settings.DATABASES['default']['PASSWORD'], db=settings.DATABASES['default']['NAME'], charset='utf8');
    cursor=conn.cursor();
    cursor.execute('select 1'); 
    cursor.fetchone()
    """, number=100
)
# 2.5417470932006836
```

And, the same thing but assuming we already have a cursor that is ready to execute a statement:

```
timeit.timeit("""
    cursor.execute('select 1'); 
    cursor.fetchone()""", 
  setup="""
    import MySQLdb;
    import settings; 
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host=settings.DATABASES['default']['HOST'], port=3306, user=settings.DATABASES['default']['USER'], passwd=settings.DATABASES['default']['PASSWORD'], db=settings.DATABASES['default']['NAME'], charset='utf8');
    cursor=conn.cursor()
    """, number=100
)
# 0.1153109073638916
```

And so we see that the second approach is about 20x faster on initialization time when we don't have to create a new connection/cursor each time.

But how would it be possible to do something like this in a serverless environment? For example, if I were using Google Cloud Functions or Cloud Run, would it be possible to:

1. Authenticate the user in order to set up a cursor to the database; and
2. Open a websocket where they can then send the query each time? (For an open websocket, do we need to check authentication on the user each time?)

Or, is there a possible approach to deal with the above overhead in a serverless environment?

Comment: 1) I recommend breaking your question into several. Database guys might not be able to answer WebSocket questions. 2) For Cloud Run, you can set up the database connection handle in global space and then reuse that handle for subsequent client calls. That requires the container is hot and not cold starting to reuse the database handle. 2) Your connection code might not work in Cloud Run depending on the database (Cloud SQL or another MySQL service).

Comment: 3) You would not normally reauthenticate messages once switched to WebSockets mode. WebSockets are complex to implement in Cloud Run because a request could go to any Cloud Run container instance and not necessarily the one you opened the database connection at.

Comment: As suggested by @JohnHanley, the websocket request could go to any cloud run container.
Check the related document for [Websocket Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/websockets) and [Client Reconnects](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/websockets#client-reconnects).
Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @David542, ,let me know if the document was useful for you ,or if you are looking for further information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AS @John Hanley mentioned, on Cloud Run, your code can either run continuously as a service or as a job. Both services and jobs run in the same environment and can use the same integrations with other services on Google Cloud.

- Cloud Run services-Used to run code that responds to web requests, or
  events.
- Cloud Run jobs. Used to run code that performs work (a job) and quits
  when the work is done.

A Cloud Run instance that has at least one open WebSocket connection is considered active and is therefore billed [Websocket connection](https://cloud.google.com/run/pricing#billable-time).
WebSockets applications are supported on Cloud Run with no additional configuration required. However, WebSockets streams are HTTP requests still subject to the [request timeout](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/request-timeout),configured for your Cloud Run service, so you need to make sure this setting works well for your use of WebSockets such as [implementing reconnects](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/websockets#client-reconnects) in your clients.
I would also recommend you check links for a [socket instance](https://socket.io/docs/v3/server-socket-instance#disconnect) and [sql connect functions](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-functions).